# xaml how center text in a templated button

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, button, viewbox

I am not able to center text in the templated button. "OK" stays at bottom center or even goes bellow the button border.

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="BT_Kids" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44.8" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71.2">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF4363EA" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
            <Viewbox>
                <ContentControl Margin="10" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,2.4">

    <Button 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="75" Margin="189.6,24.6,0,0" 
            Template="{DynamicResource BT_Kids}"  FontSize="15">OK</Button>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `ViewBox`, adjust the `FontSize` of the `Button` and set the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties of the `ContentPresenter` to `Center`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BT_Kids" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44.8" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71.2">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF4363EA" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Button 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="75" Margin="189.6,24.6,0,0"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        Template="{DynamicResource BT_Kids}" FontSize="30">OK</Button>
```

[image]

It makes no sense to put the content in a `ViewBox` when the `Ellipse` has a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Button ...>
  <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="OK"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
</Button>
```